# Disable "Angular Hint: Events, Modules, Controllers" in Chrome

Tags: angularjs, google-chrome-extension

This morning I noticed "Angular Hint: Events" "Angular Hint: Modules" and "Angular Hint: Controllers" appearing in my Chrome Console.

Where did that come from?

It seems useful, but I don't want to see it right now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found out it is from the "Batarang" Chrome extension. Just disable Batarang and it will stop.